# Read Column Values Between Two Rows CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV which is in the format:

```
Name1,Value1
,Value2
,Value3
Name2,Value40
,Value50
,Value60
Name3,Value5
,Value10
,Value15
```

There is not a set number of "values" per "name".
There is not pattern to the names.

I want to read the Values for Each Name into a dict such as:

```
Name1 : [Value1,Value2,Value3]
Name2 : [Value40,Value50,Value60] 
etc.
```

My current code is this:

```
CSVFile = open("GroupsCSV.csv")
Reader = csv.reader(CSVFile)
for row in Reader:
    if row[0] and row[2]:
        objlist = []
        objlist.append(row[2])
        for row in Reader:
            if not row[0] and row[2]:
                objlist.append(row[2])
            else:
                break
        print(objlist)
```

This half-works.
It will do Name1,Name3,Name5,Name7 etc.
I cant seem to find a way to stop it `skipping`.

Would prefer to do this without the use of something like Lambda (as its not something i fully understand yet!).
EDIT: Image of example csv (real data has another unnecessary column, hence the "row[2]" in the code.: [image]

Comment: Does your CSV have endlines or \n ? Or is it just one long line by itself?

Comment: Also, can you share a bit of the CSV data or is that impossible?

Comment: is`[blank]` the actual string `'[blank]'` or the empty string `''`?

Comment: Updated OP with Picture. [blank] = empty string.

Comment: @Dr.Pepper: then just put empy string already, don't put `[blank]`, which will confuse everyone. As long as there's a comma, it'll read in fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', header=None)

(df.ffill()                # fill the blank with the previous Name
  .groupby([0])[1]         # collect those with same name
  .apply(list)             # put those in a list
  .to_dict()               # make a dictionary
)
```

Output:

```
{'Name1': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'],
 'Name2': ['Value40', 'Value50', 'Value60'],
 'Name3': ['Value5', 'Value10', 'Value15']}
```

---

Update: the pure python(3) solution:

```
with open('your_file.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

d = {}
for line in lines:
    row = line.split(',')
    if row[0] != '': 
        key = row[0]
        d[key] = []

    d[key].append(row[1])

d
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a non-pandas way to solve this? I only ask as i have never looked into pandas before, so would like to know the non-pandas way before i delve into my learning of it!

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it. Just out of interest, is it not possible using CSV Reader because of how CSVReader iterates over the file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `csv` package. I almost always use `pandas` to handle `csv` files.

Comment: You beat me to it, I was writing the same answer :S

Comment: Very neat and tidy answer, thanks again Quang! Didnt think of the logic like that!

Comment: Can it be done with `df.pivot()` or `stack/unstack` though? I tried unsuccessfully for quite a while. Also, `.apply(pd.Series.tolist, axis=1, result_type='reduce')`

Comment: @smci `df.pivot_table(0,1, argfunc=list)` would work

Comment: Quang: neat, why not simplify your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are facing is because of your nested loop. Both loops are pointing to the same iterator. You are starting the second loop after it finds Name1 and breaking it when it finds Name2. By the time the outer loops continues after the break you have already skipped Name2.

You could have both conditions in the same loop:

```py
# with open("GroupsCSV.csv") as csv_file:
#     reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
reader = [[1,2,3],[None,5,6]] # Mocking the csv input
objlist = []
for row in reader:
    if row[0] and row[2]:
        objlist.clear()
        objlist.append(row[2])

    elif not row[0] and row[2]:
        objlist.append(row[2])
    print(objlist)
```

EDIT: I have updated the code to provide a testable output. 
The printed output looks as follows:

```
[3]
[3, 6]
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I run it and print out the objlist.